# IOS6 UITabBarController didSelectViewController Event

Tags: ios, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have created an application with the 'Tabbed Application' template. As usual, 2 tabs are created by default and linked to the firstViewController and secondViewController.

May I know how to get the didSelectViewController event with the 'Tabbed Application' template so that I can implement something when the first tab is clicked?

I have tried many solutions online but it seems that they are not for the 'Tabbed Application' template.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: what you want to do on tab selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you've created "Tabbed Application" template then in your AppDelegate.m file there must be

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

this method in comment at the end side of that file so just uncomment that method and use this and if not provided then use this method to achive your desired output  and make sure there is a tab delegate in AppDelegate.h file

Comment: i don't think it's the problem from xcode though i'm using Version 4.6.2 (4H1003) scode please upload the snapshot with your selection on tab based application i wanna make sure to help you out

Comment: Please use the link ( http://rapidshare.com/files/798299059/Test.zip ) to download the snapshot. Thanks.

Comment: @SpikeChan : I think i found the issue, it's storyboard that causes the problem if storyboard is not compulsory for your project then create simple xib based application and you'll be able to do modifications with coding.. if you wish to try then just create a test app without storyboard with tabbased app in that app you'll find what i said in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I will try to work without storyboard. ;)